# Autocomplete option using KnockoutJS

Tags: autocomplete, knockout.js

I am trying to implement autocomplete  textbox using knockoutJS in MVC3 Razor.
Copied the HTML and Script from **jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/YNCTY/** and tried executing 
it. This throws an error **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"**(found this in firebug/chrome console) in the line **ko.applyBindings(viewModel);​**

Note: I have added the required references and embedded the script in script tags.

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I am stuck.BTW I am pretty new to knockoutJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get autocomplete textbox working using 
https://github.com/madcapnmckay/Knockout-UI/tree/master/examples